# Inner Join vs Subquery efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two SQL tables, Countries and CountriesI18N:

```
Countries > Code
CountriesI18N > CountryCode, LanguageCode, Name
```

I am getting a list of Countries selecting the following:

1. Code of Countries.
2. Name of CountriesI18N given a language.

The first T-SQL option is the following:

```
SELECT [x].[Code], (
  SELECT TOP(1) [z].[Name]
  FROM [CountriesI18N] AS [z]
  WHERE ([z].[LanguageCode] = 'en' AND ([x].[Code] = [z].[CountryCode])
) AS [Name]
FROM [Countries] AS [x]
```

[image]

And and alternative using Inner Join:

```
SELECT [x].[Code], [x.CountriesI18N].[Name]
FROM [Countries] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [CountriesI18N] ON [x].[Code] = [x.CountriesI18N].[CountryCode]
WHERE [x.CountriesI18N].[LanguageCode] = 'en'
```

[image]

Are they equivalente in terms of speed and efficiency?

If I would have many related tables using many InnerJoins or Subqueries is equivalent?

Comment: Open SSMS. Press `<ctrl>+N`. In the new query window, paste both queries. Press `<ctrl>+M`. Run the queries. Check the execution plan. [Race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: "child query" = subquery :)

Comment: The short answer it: `it depends`.  Table sizes, indexes, fragmentation, data-types, even the number of columns in a table, they all have an impact.   ***Generally*** if you can write it as a `JOIN`, you probably should; the optimiser is most familiar with that, it's easier for humans to read and maintain, etc, etc.  But which uses the most resources, and which is faster *(They're not the same thing; a single threaded plan can take longer and yet use fewer resources than a multi-threaded plan)* is best measured using SQL Server's profiler and/or looking at the execution plans.

Comment: Also, your queries are not the same.  The first guarantees one name per code.  The second allows for the possibility of multiple names per code.  That they ***can*** generate different results will likely mean that they generate different execution plans.  All the more reasons for checking the execution plans to see *how* different they are, and using the profiler to accurately measure use of resources.

Comment: @MatBailie How would I change the second query to get only one name? In fact in the CountriesLocalization I have a unique constraint on  <CountryCode, LanguageCode> because that is the PK. So I know that for each LanguageCode I will only get one Name.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn You're right. Haven't use SQL for a while. Just updated my question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura - Add a column with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.code ORDER BY y.something) AS seq_num` to it so that you can then wrap it in another query and add `WHERE seq_num = 1`.  Or just put a `MIN()` or `MAX()` around the `Name` being selected.  There are many ways, but it would depend on what you're trying to achieve.  *(But this is micro-optimisation. Time & effort is likely best placed else where.  As a principle write the most maintainable code that robustly achieves your requirements.  Optimise after it works, and only where necessary.  I've seen many man-Months lost this way)*

Comment: @MatBailie I am using an ORM and I am trying to determine if there are really big differences in terms of performance for these two queries. When I execute the queries the time taken is very similar. I just posted the execution plan for each one.

Comment: Look at the first operator in each plan (the SELECT) and see if in the properties there are any significant differences in the cost and operation of each plan

Comment: @MartinCairney Yes, the cost of the subquery is 0.056 and the one with Inner Join is 0,016

Comment: @MiguelMoura in THIS specific case, your Inner Join version is more efficient.  However if the number of records changes then it may not always remain that way.

Answer (score 0):

First, they are not equivalent queries.  For your particular data, they may *look* equivalent but they are not.  The subquery returns up-to-one match.  The `inner join` filters out non-matches and can return duplicates.

So, you are comparing apples and oranges.

In either case, you want an index on 
`CountriesI18N(CountryCode, LanguageCode)`.  This happens to be the best index for both versions of the query.

Comment: (CountryCode, LanguageCode) is already the PK of CountriesI18N as a composite key ... So that covers it, right?

Comment: Yes, I know that they are not the same ... I will try some to make inner join similar to the subquery to compare in similar conditions